# How to echo Wordpress Author ID in author.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

i have a custom theme with frontend E-Mail and Facebook login. Every user gets the author role by default after registration.

How can i echo the USERS ID in the frontend wich shows up by hovering about the users name in the backend?  I tried this:

```
<?php echo the_author_ID(); ?>
```

But it does not works for the admin role and Users who logged in with facebook? The id shows up with hovering in the backend... Any idea?

Update: i will show the IDs of the users who are registered - in their frontend author.php AND not the ID of the current user who is logged in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for this,

```
the_author_meta("ID");
```

The

```
the_author_ID();
```

function has been deprecated.

Comment: OHHHHH - now i know wy it does not echo the ID from some users!!! If there is no post published from the user it does not show up the ID!!! both of your codes work fine - the second one i already used, but now i know the problem. thx

Answer (score 3):

It is specific only to users with `user_role=author` If you want admin roles and users from facebook login you can try `get_current_user_id()`

Comment: Hi - does not work. I tried this before! It shows me the id of the current logged in user and not the id of the reigstered users in their forntend author.php view! i edited my question. thx

Comment: so you want list of ids for all the users who reigstered.
then why not try get_users? you can specify get_users scope also

`$allusers = get_users(); foreach($allusers as $cuser){ echo $cuser->ID; }`

Comment: now i know wy it does not echo the ID from some users!!! If there is no post published from the user it does not show up the ID!!! thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_current_user_id()`.Returns the ID of the current viewer if they are logged in. Returns 0 if the viewer is not logged in. you can try for current user like this :

```
 <?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
} else {
    echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
}
?>
```

> OR

You can also try  `current user object (WP_User)`.Retrieve the current user object (WP_User).

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    /**
     * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
     *     return;
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';

 <?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi - does not work. I tried this before! It shows me the id of the current logged in user and not the id of the reigstered users in their forntend author.php view! Again - i only will show the users id in the frontend - anyone should see the id, regardless of logged in or not. Every user has its own author url like: xxxxxx.com/user/anyuser and exactly in this site i will echo the ID of the "anyuser" for example?